# UWP disable rotate a specific control

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

In my Project I have two buttons:

```
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="FirstButton"
            Content="First"/>
    <Button x:Name="SecondButton"
            Content="Second"/>
</Grid/>
```

I would like to know if there's any way when I change the orientation of the device only the `FirstButton` change his orientation, and `SecondButton` don't change his orientation.

Already grateful for any help!

Comment: I know that using the method: DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences, I can lock the orientation of the application, could I use something like that to the control?

Comment: Yes. https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/DisplayOrientation/cs/Scenario1_Orientation.xaml.cs

Comment: But then lock the rotation of the entire application, I would like lock only the orientation of the `FirstButton`.

Comment: In den designer while your button is selected add a rotation transform, give it a key and change the angle in code behind when the device rotates.